# Is it possible to change the audio route of an AVPlayer with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I have an AVPlayer that plays audio in streaming or with an audio file.
The `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]` is configured with the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` category.
 It plays in foreground and background and everything works fine.
 I would like to add the functionality described in this SO question [How to play audio through built-in earpiece speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692577/how-to-play-audio-through-built-in-earpiece-speaker) when the app is not in the background.
I have read the question above and the documentation that says:

> You can programmatically influence the audio output route. When using the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord category, audio normally goes to the receiver (the small speaker you hold to your ear when on a phone call). You can redirect audio to the speaker at the bottom of the phone by using the overrideOutputAudioPort:error: method.

So my question is: can I change the audio route of my AVPlayer maintaining the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` or do I have to switch to  `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`?
Are there any disadvantages changing the category to  `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You strongly need to use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` because audio route change via `overrideOutputAudioPort` doesn't work with `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` (docs by Apple)

No any significant difference between `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` and `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` is found.

Comment: Not sure why this was written, this is incorrect. If you connect this session via a BLE device or speaker, you will hear the difference. The PlayAndRecord route will sound like you are listening via a phone. Playback will give you the sound quality similar to listening to HD music.

Answer (score 0):

**AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord** is required for VOIP scenario where you play and record the voice simultaneously.
In your case you don't need to use **AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord**.
**AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback** will be enough for **AVPlayer**. As you are just playing audio file or streaming.

Thanks