# How do you enable mic mode in new iOS 15?

Tags: swift, ios15

With the new iOS version there's a new mic mode that i need to enable on my app. However i don't see any example in Google or in YouTube. If someone can help me in showing how to enable mic mode in new iOS 15, would be great help.

Thankyou. [image]

Comment: I've added picture to my question. With the new Mic Mode, Apple offers you a way to choose what others hear from your side during a video/voice call through machine learning. The new mode gives you two additional options besides the Standard mode – Voice Isolation and Wide Spectrum.

Comment: I had to delete my post. While the preferredAudioMode does exist, apple doesn't allow you to change it. It's a system setting that only the user can set via control center, it cannot be controlled from within an app. I looked through the documentation for like 20 minutes and searched through Google for any related "microphone mode"

Comment: Exactly... I wanted to ask you the same but took me sometime to figure this out. However it seems we have to configure something in a way where it allows our app to access all the modes and allows user to select it. Checked in macOS and iOS too. WhatsApp, Snapchat, zoom has already integrated this.

Comment: Finding it really hard to get this thing done without any example and with less knowledge about AVCaptureDevice

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally achieve this by configuring the audio session for my app.
Follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608869) along and this will set up the mic mode for the app.

Comment: I tried the code that you liked in the post but didnt work, did you do any other configuration that helped?

Comment: Nope. That's all copied and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use `AVCaptureDevice` to capture audio, you could do a trick as follows. Just initialise `AVAudioEngine` and set-up `AVAudioInputNode`.

```
AVAudioInputNode *inputNode = _audioEngine.inputNode;

[inputNode setVoiceProcessingEnabled:YES error:&error];
[inputNode setVoiceProcessingAGCEnabled:YES];
```

This will enable the menu with microphone modes. And the sound coming from `AVCaptureDevice` will be also filtered by those modes.